# Create PNG using writeGDAL without georeference (.aux.xml)

Tags: r, png, rgdal

When creating a PNG file using writeGDAL, a georeferencing file is created (.aux.xml) along with the PNG file. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

The following code creates the files as explained above.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

r <- raster(xmn=742273.5, xmx=742702.5, ymn=6812515.5, ymx=6812995.5, ncols=144, nrows=161)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))

rSpdf <- as(r, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
rSpdf$colors <- as.numeric(cut(rSpdf$layer, breaks = 10))

writeGDAL(rSpdf[, 'colors'], 'test.png', drivername = 'PNG', type = 'Byte', mvFlag = 0, colorTables = list(colorRampPalette(c('black', 'white'))(11)))
```

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123832/r-how-to-write-a-raster-to-disk-without-auxiliary-file) could be of interest for you

Comment: That is was what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `rgdal::setCPLConfigOption("GDAL_PAM_ENABLED", "FALSE")` the .aux.xml file is not created.
Thank you [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5997555/val) for pointing me to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123832/r-how-to-write-a-raster-to-disk-without-auxiliary-file).

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

rgdal::setCPLConfigOption("GDAL_PAM_ENABLED", "FALSE")

r <- raster(xmn=742273.5, xmx=742702.5, ymn=6812515.5, ymx=6812995.5, ncols=144, nrows=161)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))

rSpdf <- as(r, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
rSpdf$colors <- as.numeric(cut(rSpdf$layer, breaks = 10))

writeGDAL(rSpdf[, 'colors'], 'test.png', drivername = 'PNG', type = 'Byte', mvFlag = 0, colorTables = list(colorRampPalette(c('black', 'white'))(11)))
```